# Problem plotting dot size and colour for different variables (ggplot, geom_dot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a melted dataset and I'm trying to generate a dot plot (or "bubble" plot) showing mean values as dot size, and p_value as dot colour. I can do either size or colour independently, however (as shown below), if I try to do both size and colour, the size of the dots end up the same size between samples. Thank you for any assistance!

Here is the data:

```
Interaction_Pair__Cluster_Pair  mean    sample  p_value
ANXA1_FPR2 CD8..srm.Ppan...Myeloid  0.1 UT  0.841
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.CD4 0   UT  1
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.CD8..srm.Ppan.  0   UT  1
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.Cytoxic.CD8 0   UT  1
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.Proliferative   0   UT  1
CCR4_CCL17 Myeloid.Unknown  0.023   UT  0.988
CCR3_CCL7 Tregs.Myeloid 0.027   UT  0.147
CCR3_CCL15 Tregs.Myeloid    0.175   UT  0
ANXA1_FPR2 CD8..srm.Ppan...Myeloid  0.236   UT  0.841
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.CD4 0.394   UT  1
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.CD8..srm.Ppan.  0.512   UT  1
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.Cytoxic.CD8 0.298   UT  1
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.Proliferative   0.36    UT  1
CCR4_CCL17 Myeloid.Unknown  0.205   UT  0.988
CCR3_CCL7 Tregs.Myeloid 0.205   UT  0.147
CCR3_CCL15 Tregs.Myeloid    0.453   UT  0
ANXA1_FPR2 CD8..srm.Ppan...Myeloid  0.1 aCT 0
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.CD4 0   aCT 0
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.CD8..srm.Ppan.  0   aCT 0
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.Cytoxic.CD8 0   aCT 0
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.Proliferative   0   aCT 0
CCR4_CCL17 Myeloid.Unknown  0.023   aCT 0
CCR3_CCL7 Tregs.Myeloid 0.027   aCT 0
CCR3_CCL15 Tregs.Myeloid    0.175   aCT 0
ANXA1_FPR2 CD8..srm.Ppan...Myeloid  0.236   aCT 0
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.CD4 0.394   aCT 0
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.CD8..srm.Ppan.  0.512   aCT 0
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.Cytoxic.CD8 0.298   aCT 0
GMCSFR_CSF2 Myeloid.Proliferative   0.36    aCT 0
CCR4_CCL17 Myeloid.Unknown  0.205   aCT 0
CCR3_CCL7 Tregs.Myeloid 0.205   aCT 0
CCR3_CCL15 Tregs.Myeloid    0.453   aCT 0
```

Here is the code for the plot which I'm having issue with.

```
ggplot(gg, (aes(x=sample, y=Interaction_Pair__Cluster_Pair, color = as.numeric(p_value), size=ifelse(as.numeric(mean)==0, NA, as.numeric(mean))))) + 
  geom_point()
```

And here is the plot it generates.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked your data ? The reason the dot size is the same between samples is because the mean value IS the same between samples. *e.g* plot this : `ggplot(dat, aes(x = sample, y = mean)) + geom_point(alpha = .1) + geom_text(aes(label = Interaction_Pair__Cluster_Pair))`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me back to the data, turns out it was an error when I melted the data, shifted values so that sample values were identical, didn't realise that was possible.